# Find start date and end date across multiple records of uninterrupted days - MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have records which contain a start date and end date. These represent the time an employee spent working on at a job site.

I'm trying to determine the **most recent** stretch of **continuous** days an employee worked – where there was no time off.

I need the start date and the end date from that range

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE `emp_data` (
 `employee` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `start_date` date NOT NULL,
 `end_date` date NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `emp_data` (`employee`, `start_date`, `end_date`) VALUES ('Brian', '2022-04-15', '2022-04-20'), ('Brian', '2022-04-21', '2022-05-05'),('Brian', '2022-05-25', '2022-05-31'),('Brian', '2022-06-01', '2022-06-06'),('Doug', '2022-04-25', '2022-04-29'),('Doug', '2022-05-18', '2022-05-19'), ('Doug', '2022-05-20', '2022-06-01');
```

```
Brian | 2022-04-15 | 2022-04-20
Brian | 2022-04-21 | 2022-05-05 
Brian | 2022-05-25 | 2022-05-31 
Brian | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-06 
Doug  | 2022-04-25 | 2022-04-29 
Doug  | 2022-05-18 | 2022-05-19
Doug  | 2022-05-20 | 2022-06-01
```

The result I'm looking for:

```
Brian | 2022-05-25 | 2022-06-06
Doug  | 2022-05-18 | 2022-06-01
```

Comment: What you are exactly pointing with word *no gaps*. A detailed example can help to understand the problem. Thanks,

Comment: I'm trying to piece together the beginning and end of a continuous range across multiple records.

Comment: Better data and build query added.

Comment: you can try to use [Having](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) and [Max/Min](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) to deal with your issue